# Not able to solve the style tag validation issue in body

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am getting the HTML validation error below:

> Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

I have used the `scoped` attribute from HTML 5.1 on a `style` tag:

```
<style scoped>
```

Any idea what is the root cause?

Comment: `<style>`should be in the `<head>` not as an child for any element in the `<body>`

Comment: Yes but am using wordpress plugins, I think is there any way if it's in body and we can solve it still ?

Comment: No, because the `<style>`tag should be in the `<head>`, if you care about validation, replace it, leave it in the `<body>`if you care less.

Comment: anyway, if its a plugin, maybe contact the writer off the plugin, he should care that his CSS is appended to the right place in the DOM

Comment: If scoped attribute was still around then it would be ok to have the style tag in the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is this:

> The scoped attribute has been removed from the specification after only limited and experimental adoption by Chrome and Firefox.

The browser support is as follows:

- Supported in Chrome 20+ to 34 by enabling the "Enable " or "experimental WebKit features" flag in chrome://flags. Removed in Chrome 35+ due to code complexity.
- Gecko 20 and later implement :scope pseudo-class, but the preference layout.css.scope-pseudo.enabled must be set to true. This is only the case by default in Nightly and Aurora test versions.

**References**

- [MDN: A scoped stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#A_scoped_stylesheet)
- [Blink dev: Intent to remove `<style scoped>`](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/scoped/blink-dev/R1x18ZLS5qQ/Bjuh_cENhlQJ)